# ような (you na) vs ように (you ni) grammar question

Tags: grammar

I have learnt that ように (*you ni*) can modify a verb. And ような (*you na*) modifies a noun. (I am not sure that is quite correct or not). Today I came across this sentence in "NHK easy Japanese" :

> 物を売る仕事になかなか人が集まらないため、店で働く人が集まる​**ように**、休みを多くしました

1. Firstly I don't know what it actually means.
   Does it mean:
   Because not a lot of people selling goods, many people took holidays by working inside the shops (!?).
2. 休み【やすみ】 (*yasumi*) is a noun, so why is ように used instead of ような?

Thank you very much

Comment: "*And You Na modifies a Noun*" -- any example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means: Because the job of selling goods does not attract people, (we) increased holidays to attract more people to work in the shops.

店で働く人が集まるように (to attract more people to work in the shops) does not modify 休み, but the verb 多くしました, or the sentence 休みを多くしました. So this does not contradict the rule.

Comment: Thank you very much. Great help to me.